# UIView animated changes with auto layout constraints

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, autolayout

Say that I have a project which looks like the following:

[image]

There are two `UIView`s - one called `yellowBox` and the other called `redBox`. The auto layout constraints dictate that the `yellowBox` is 60 points from the top of the superview with 350 points leading and trailing spaces (i.e. to left and right of the view). The `redBox` has the same leading and trailing space constraints. There is a vertical space constraint between the two boxes of 0 to indicate that the bottom of the `yellowBox` should always be directly on top of the `redBox`.

When the user taps the Expand Yellow Box button, I would like the height of the `yellowBox` to increase and, as a result, the `redBox` moves down to continue satisfying the vertical space constraint (that the `yellowBox` is always on top of the `redBox`). Here is the animation code:

```
- (IBAction)expandYellowBox:(id)sender {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                     animations:^{
                         CGRect newFrame = self.yellowBox.frame;
                         newFrame.size.height += 50;
                         self.yellowBox.frame = newFrame;
                     }];

}
```

However, I have been unable to get this working properly. As you can see by the red icon, there is a problem with the constraints at the moment:

[image]

which is fair enough, as there's no way for auto layout to know the height of the boxes. However, I don't know how to resolve this issue in such a way that it will allow for the boxes to be resized and moved. For example, if I specify a height constraint on the `yellowBox` then that will prevent it from being resized. If I set the height constraint to be *greater than or equal* (to allow the `yellowBox` height to increase) then I get a different constraint error:

[image]

All constraints have been established using Xcode in the storyboard - none have been written in code.

Any help greatly appreciated.

---

**EDIT:** As it turns out, the `yellowBox` is growing when the button is clicked - it's just I couldn't tell because it appears behind the `redBox`. I only noticed after clicking it around four times and it started appearing out the bottom of the `redBox`. However, the same question still remains - how to get the `redBox` to always stick to the bottom of the `yellowBox`.

Comment: can u check wether viewDidLayoutSubViews method called in ur viewController? When perform click event.

Comment: No, the `viewDidLayoutSubViews` method is not called.

Comment: try to set the bound instead of frame may work some time. even repeat self.yellowBox.frame = newFrame; twice in u code may also fix some times

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, plus repeating code several times (until it takes) doesn't seem to be the best solution to the issue...

Comment: check my answer and demo. this will help

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Try it as mentioned by [shwet-solanki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1066748/shwet-solanki), but add the following line after changing the constraint:

```
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

the IBAction would look like:

```
- (IBAction)expandYellowBox:(id)sender {

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                 animations:^{
                     self.yellowBoxHeightConstraint.constant += 50;
                     [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                 }];
}
```

Where `yellowBoxHeightConstraint` is the `IBOutlet` for height constraint of `yellowBox`.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this is the exact approach which I am trying to avoid. I don't want to have to manually adjust the frame of the `redBox`, as that should move by virtue of the constraints. It's trivial in this case, but the example in this question is just a test project to demonstrate the issue - the actual problem occurs in a much bigger project where using the approach which you have suggested would unfortunately not be feasible or maintainable.

Comment: I hope u have noticed that i have edited my answer. The current method should work. Do try it out.

Comment: I have also posted a follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21033146/animating-auto-layout-constraint-change-on-uicollectionview

Comment: Be careful with layoutIfNeeded, since it performs a layout immediately and that can cause undesired effects in some circumstances (such as when you use it from scrollView:didScroll to tie animation to the scrolling of a view, which triggers a LOT of events). It is also very demanding. In those cases it's better to use setNeedsLayout, which will layout things but when the UI thread has time.

Comment: thanks for the pointer @ncerezo. I have come across such situations in live projects and `setNeedsLayout` indeed is recommended in that case.

Comment: @GoGreen...thank you...I was calling `layoutIfNeeded` on my `UIImageView` instead of view

Answer (score 4):

1. Add Height constraint to both the views
2. Create an IBOutlet for height constraint of yellowbox
3. Now instead of changing the height of yellowbox in the button pressed event, rather change the value of the height constraint. i.e suppose your IBOutlet constraint name is yellowBoxHeightConstraint, then `yellowBoxHeightConstraint.constant += 50;`

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks, that does expand the `yellowBox` (with the `redBox` pinned to the bottom of the `yellowBox`) but it does not animate the change - it happens suddenly.

Answer (score 1):

```
//
//  WPViewController.h
//  AutoLayoutTEst
//
//  Created by VASANTH K on 09/01/14.
//  
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface WPViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button1;
- (IBAction)buttClicked:(id)sender;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstrain;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button2;
@end
```

**click Event**

```
- (IBAction)buttClicked:(id)sender {


    self.heightConstrain.constant=100;


}
```

here u need to set the `heightConstrain` for the Yellow button then create reference outlet for that button then update the `heightConstrain` to update the size of that button it will automatically move your Red button down.

https://github.com/vasanth3008/AutoLayoutHeighDemo

refer my sample demo project