# Animating auto layout constraint change on UICollectionView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, autolayout

Following on from a [previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21014087/uiview-animated-changes-with-auto-layout-constraints) which I asked, I am attempting to animate the change in height of a `UICollectionView` (which is `yellowBox` in the example). This change in height is being triggered by modifying the auto layout constraints on the collection view with the following code:

```
- (IBAction)expandYellowBox:(id)sender {

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                 animations:^{
                     self.yellowBoxHeightConstraint.constant += 50;
                     [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                 }];
}
```

However, when I call `[self.view layoutIfNeeded]` this results in the collection view being reloaded, so it flashes visibly to the user. However, I don't want the collection view to reload but instead just to animate its height change. Is there any way to either avoid `-layoutIfNeeded` reloading the collection view, or an alternative way to animate the constraint height change which doesn't call a method which has the side-effect of reloading the collection view?

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone else encounters this problem, it was because I was actually calling `[self.collectionView reloadData]` a few lines above the animation block (and didn't notice!). It seems that calling `-reloadData` and `-layoutIfNeeded` causes the collection view to flash. Removing the call to `-reloadData` resolves the problem.