# Auto Layout constraint change does not animate

Tags: ios, ios7, autolayout, uiviewanimation, ios10

I was learning the auto layout with animations from the tutorial

http://weblog.invasivecode.com/post/42362079291/auto-layout-and-core-animation-auto-layout-was

and things were working perfect.

When I tried to use this concept in my application, trying to animate a settings screen(a UIView) from bottom to top,it works great when the settings screen is just an empty UIView,

But in case I add a UILabel as a subview to this settings screen, the animation just vanishes. 
On removing this UILabel form the settings screen, the animation is visible.

Here are the outlets that I have connected

```
__weak IBOutlet UIView *settingsView;
__weak IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *settingsBottomConstraint;
__weak IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *settingsViewHeightConstraint;
```

View did load setup method(setupViews)

```
-(void)setupViews
{
    settingsBottomConstraint.constant = - settingsViewHeightConstraint.constant;
    [settingsView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    [settingsView layoutIfNeeded];
    isSettingsHidden = YES;
}
```

Hide/Unhide Method

```
- (IBAction)showSettingsScreen:(id)sender {

    if (isSettingsHidden) {

        settingsBottomConstraint.constant = 0;
        [settingsView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.3 animations:^{
            [settingsView layoutIfNeeded];
        }];
    }
    else{

        settingsBottomConstraint.constant = - settingsViewHeightConstraint.constant;
        [settingsView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            [settingsView layoutIfNeeded];
        }];

    }
    isSettingsHidden = !isSettingsHidden;
}
```

My issue seems similar to the 
[Issue with UIView Auto Layout Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168873/issue-with-uiview-auto-layout-animation)

Comment: what are the constraints on your UILabel?

Comment: @Iftekhar, I had tried both the options . 1. Just by dropping the lable to the UIView(i.e. with no constraints) and 2. Adding constrains for width, height, top space to superview and leading to superview. None worked.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I found the answer.

Instead of,

```
[settingsView layoutIfNeeded];
```

this line made it worked like charm,

```
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

I suppose we need to perform layoutIfNeeded method on the parent view not just the view we are trying to animate.

**UPDATE:**
As pointed out in a comment by codyko, this is required for **iOS 7, iOS 10**.
For iOS 8 this issue does not exists.

Comment: Note that [settingsView layoutIfNeeded] works in iOS8, but NOT in iOS7. In iOS7 you need to call [self.view layoutIfNeeded] instead, but if you're only working in iOS8, you don't need to update constraints for the whole view.