# iOS constraints not updating as expected

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have a superview with circle view and a holderview that contains 3 labels as subview and is centred to the superview as seen in image 
[image]

I have added constraints to the 3 labels with respect to holderview and also added constraints to holderview with respect to superview

```
NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(titleLabel);
NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-[titleLabel]-|"
                                        options:0
                                        metrics:nil
                                          views:viewsDictionary];

[holderView addConstraints:constraints];


viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(setLabel);
constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-[setLabel]-|"
                                        options: 0
                                        metrics:nil
                                          views:viewsDictionary];

[holderView addConstraints:constraints];


viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(repLabel);
constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-[repLabel]-|"
                                        options:0
                                        metrics:nil
                                          views:viewsDictionary];

[holderView addConstraints:constraints];

viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(titleLabel, setLabel, repLabel);
constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[titleLabel]-0-[setLabel]-0-[repLabel]-|"
                                        options:0
                                        metrics:nil
                                          views:viewsDictionary];

[holderView addConstraints:constraints];


NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_labelView);
    NSArray *constraints =[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-[_labelView]-|"
                                                                  options:0
                                                                  metrics:nil
                                                                    views:viewsDictionary];
    [self addConstraints:constraints];
```

There is a feature in app where the circle shrinks. I want the holderview and its subivews to shrink dynamically. Adding the constraints works for holderview but the subviews get misaligned.

[image]
[image]

To shrink i update the frame size of the holderview as the superview frame changes.

Can anyone point out the mistakes and guide me to proper solution ?

Comment: You should show the code for how you handle the shrink. If you're actually modifying the frame of the holder view, that's wrong -- you should be doing that with constraints. What constraints do you have between the superview and holder view?

Comment: Actually you are right i was updating the frame of holder view also. But the constraints should take care of it. It works as expected now. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Using auto layout and changing frame property messes up things.

Create oultest to the constraints that you want to change or animate

```
__weak IBOutlet UIView *settingsView;
__weak IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *settingsBottomConstraint;
__weak IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *settingsViewHeightConstraint;
```

Update the constrains(Never the frame!)

```
settingsBottomConstraint.constant = - settingsViewHeightConstraint.constant;
[settingsView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
[settingsView layoutIfNeeded];
isSettingsHidden = YES;
```

Recently I have worked with animation of views with autolayout and you can find your answer here
[Auto Layout constraint change does not animate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23028701/auto-layout-uiview-on-constraint-change-does-not-animate)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the function `updateConstraints`.

```
[settingsView updateConstraints];
```