# Tableview cell separator jumps in iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've read through several related [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39104846/uitableviewcell-animate-height-issue-in-ios-10) for how to deal with cell height animation changes in iOS 10. Based on several answers I've been able to create a work-around for animating the contents of the cell, but I'm surprised the cell separator is broken in the GM from Apple. Maybe this is naive but it seems like something that would get caught sooner.

[image: example of cell separator jumping]

I'm asking a new question to make sure I'm not missing something obvious. Is there a better work-around in iOS 10 that doesn't involve drawing faux cell separators at the bottom of each cell?