# Autolayout not animating in iOS 10 but working fine in iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout, ios-autolayout

```
- (IBAction)btnA:(id)sender {
    if(self.height.constant == 300) {
         self.height.constant = 50;
    } else {
         self.height.constant = 300;
    }

    [self.subView1 setNeedsUpdateConstraints];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        [self.subView1 layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```

I am using this code but on `iOS10` its not animating its just jump increasing and decreasing mySubview1 height. Why?

Same code is working fine in `iOS9`

Comment: Could you try removing this line and see if it works.
[self.subView1 setNeedsUpdateConstraints];

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For iOS10 its the view's superview which you have to force layout.

```
//Force apply all constraints prior to the change in constant.
[self.view.superview layoutIfNeeded];

//Update constant
self.height.constant = 0;

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    [self.view.superview layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

I believe this behaviour is caused by the change in Xcode8 - iOS10 layout

References:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39501882

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39548367/1045672

Comment: This issue used to exist in iOS 7 too. Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23028701/auto-layout-uiview-on-constraint-change-does-not-animate/23102912#23102912

Comment: If my view is subview of UITableViewCell then what should I do? Do I use 1. [cell.subView.superView layoutIfNeeded],  2.[cell layoutIfNeeded] or 3. [cell.superview layoutIfNeed]?  Which would I use? I'm using the same code but not working in iOS 10.1. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: @JekilPatel what have you tried? Am I correct that you want to animate a subview inside a uitableviewcell? try [cell.contentview layoutifneeded]

Comment: @Teffi Yes, you are right. I'm trying to animate subView inside UITableViewCell. Thanks for the reply. Let me try with the one you provide and let you know. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Teffi I was trying to animate tableview as a subview inside the UITableViewCell with [cell.contentview layoutifneeded] unfortunately it's not working. I'm doing same code as you answered.