# How to update Constraint after change frames in code

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have two button, on both auto layout is enabled but in run time I need to change their frame . I changed but doesn't effect on them I tried many times by calling this `constraintWithItem`  method and 
    `[self.btnDeviceContacts updateConstraints];
    [self.btnFacebookContacts updateConstraints];`

also `[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
[self.view layoutSubviews];`

Its not effecting on this by calling this `constraintWithItem` only effect first button

```
    NSLayoutConstraint *constrain1 = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                 constraintWithItem:self.btnDeviceContacts
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                 toItem:nil
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                 multiplier:1
                                 constant:160];

 [self.view addConstraint:constrain2];
NSLayoutConstraint *constrain2 = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                  constraintWithItem:self.btnFacebookContacts
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                  toItem:nil
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                  multiplier:1
                                  constant:160];
NSArray * array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:constrain1,constrain2, nil];
[self.view addConstraints:array];
```

Initial Frame of Buttons on storyboard

```
[self.btnDeviceContacts setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 60, 106, self.btnDeviceContacts.frame.size.height)];
     [self.btnFacebookContacts setFrame:CGRectMake(107, 60, 106, self.btnFacebookContacts.frame.size.height)];
```

Changed frame of Button in code:

```
[self.btnDeviceContacts setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 60, 160, self.btnDeviceContacts.frame.size.height)];
     [self.btnFacebookContacts setFrame:CGRectMake(161, 60, 160, self.btnFacebookContacts.frame.size.height)];
```

Kindly help me on this, how to update constraint or how to tackle this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try `[self.view updateConstraints]` also try `[self.view layoutIfNeeded]` before updateContraints

**Edit:** use Constant Property

```
 @property (nonatomic) NSLayoutConstraint * leftSideButtonContact;
```

and just

```
leftSideButtonContact.constant = 20;  // your change in property will effect the layout directly
```

make sure you applied your constraint in .xib file

Comment: When to do this, after setting frame?

Comment: After change in frame

Comment: if you are using autolayout, never change frames explicitly!

Comment: Right, but do I need to attach leftSideButtonContact with any constraint, because how will Xcode know that leftSideButtonContact belongs to which button?

Comment: Just going to try this one.

Comment: @Jazz Strange response, attached to horizontal space and set " self.leftSideButtonContact.constant=161", now this button is not showing on screen. I done this after setting frame.

Comment: @Sulthan: Then how to deal with this, I mean updating runtime frame?

Comment: @josh did you set this _constant_ value after setting leading,trailing, bottom, top, height, width constraints set on .xib file ?

Comment: @josh Update constraints and then animate the change in constraints, there are multiple questions about that already here, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21014087/uiview-animated-changes-with-auto-layout-constraints